# How can I use datasnapshot just one time to both modells?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to call just once datasnapshot to two different models.
When I call two datasnapshot, my database is read two times. I just want to call datasnapshot once.

I tried to call twice datasnapshot but is not what I want, because is read twice and so returning null for models that don't match the objects in the database

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("feedPosts");

    Query queryFeed = databaseReference;
    childEventListener = queryFeed.limitToFirst(33).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {




            for (DataSnapshot value : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Feed_modell feed = value.getValue(Feed_modell.class);

                Book book = value.getValue(Book.class);

                // ... 
                mDataSet.add(feed);
                mDataSet.add(book);

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you say is called twice?

Comment: Because the first datasnapshot load my entire database and just retrieve the objects that matched feed and the second do the same and matched the objects that matched book. When my datasnapshot is called by the  Feed_modell feed = value.getValue(Feed_modell.class); the book vakues are retrieved as null.